# How to create new column in a df based on multiple conditions?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a df with 3 columns: v1, v2, v3;where

```
v1=[a,b,c,a] 
v2=[d,d,f,n] 
v3=[a,k,i,j]
```

What I like to do is to create new columns based on conditions in column v1~v3.

I can do single condition,

```
df['v1_a']=np.where(df['v1']=='a',1,0)
```

it gives a new column named `'v1_a'` with `1/0`

However, if I want to create a new column based on multiple conditions, this does not work:

```
df['v2_flag']=np.where(df['v2']=='f' or df['v2']=='h',1,0)
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 6):

In python `and` and `or` can only give a single result and can't be overridden to have other purposes by modules like the giant row by row comparison you're trying to do.

You need to use the symbolic `&` (and) and `|` (or), which are normally used for bit-wise comparisons.  These have been re-purposed by pandas to be a row by row comparison, which actually makes sense as being analogous to bit-wise comparisons.  That is more of a happy coincidence though, as these were mainly used because these can be overridden by the modules.

Because of the priority of these and equalities, you'll need parentheses around each term or else it would calculate the `|` before the `==` which isn't what you want.  You can use something like this:

```
df['v2_flag']=np.where((df['v2']=='f')|(df['v2']=='h'),1,0)
```

Comment: also looks like in ('f','h') does not work. Is it same reason?

Comment: @c1ez `and`, `or`, and `not` cannot be overloaded, but `&`, `|`, and even `in` can be.  Maybe they could make thaht work, though the docs say `in` should only return a single true/false, so maybe there is issues making the results an array of true false.

Answer (score 4):

If you use multiple condition you'll get the following `ValueError` because `np.where()` doesn't accept multiple condition :

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

So in your I suggest to use `np.logical_or`.

```
df['v2_flag']=np.where(np.logical_or(df['v2']=='f',df['v2']=='h'),1,0)
```

See the following example too:

```
>>> a=np.array([2,2,2,5,7,8,1,4,2,3,4,5,6])
>>> np.where(np.logical_or(a==5,a==2),a,0)
array([2, 2, 2, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 5, 0])
```

Answer (score 1):

`df['v2']=='f' or df['v2']=='h'` raises the ValueError *before* it gets to `np.where`. The `or` causes Python to evaluate `df['v2']=='f'` and `df['v2']=='h'` in a boolean context. But Pandas `Series`, like NumPy arrays, refuse to be reduce to a single boolean value -- [they raise a ValueError instead](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#using-if-truth-statements-with-pandas).

To fix your code, you could use

```
df['v2_flag'] = np.where( (df['v2']=='f') | (df['v2']=='h'), 1, 0)
```

The `|` performs bitwise-or element-wise over the two boolean-valued Series.

Other ways to define `df['v2_flag']` include

```
df['v2_flag'] = ((df['v2']=='f') | (df['v2']=='h')).astype(int)
```

or

```
df['v2_flag'] = df['v2'].isin(['f', 'h']).astype(int)
```